# How to display a list of related cases inside a pageBlockTable?

Tags: apex, visualforce, relationships

I have a pageBlockTable which has a list of custom objects (Project__c). I want to display a related list in the column of the pageBlockTable with the associated cases for each custom object.

I've tried using the  component however this seems to only be able to support one relatedList at a time across multiple components.

At the moment I'm stuck on using hoverDetail but this only shows the latest case. I have no problem returning a list of cases for the object but I don't know what component to use so I can display the returned related list.

**Apex Code**

```
  projectList=[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Cases__r ), Project_Title__c, Open_Cases_TEXT__c, Project_End_Date__c, Overdue__c,Status__c
       FROM Project__c
        ORDER BY Project_End_Date__c ASC];
```

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!projectList}" var="p" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Cases" >
        <a href="/{!p.Cases__r}" id="{!p.Id}"  onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}', '/{!p.Cases__r[0]}/m?retURL=%2F{!p.Cases__r[0]}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">{!p.Open_Cases_TEXT__c} </a>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe I've updated my post with current hoverDetail code.

Comment: sam do you want to see the cases related to the project__c as related list/ as hover or as a table inside the project table

Comment: @Rao Either will do, but I'd most prefer a related list/hoverDetail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have coded the following example with accounts and contacts

I would recommend having atleast `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to make the related list hide and fade smoother, but that's your choice

```
<apex:page controller="pageblockwithrlist">
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acclist}" var="p" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Accounts">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!p.id}" target="_blank"> {!p.name}</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="contacts">
    <apex:repeat value="{!p.contacts}" var="con"> 
        <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="/{!con.Id}" id="{!con.Id}" 
            onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!con.Id}').hide();" 
            onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!con.Id}', '/{!con.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!con.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" 
            onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!con.Id}').hide();" 
            onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!con.Id}', '/{!con.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!con.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">{!con.Name}</a>
        <br/>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </apex:repeat>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

In your code you are fetching the only the latest case related to the project

> getHover('{!p.Id}', '/{!**p.Cases__r[0]**}/m?retURL=%2F{!p.**Cases__r[0]**}

For your case all you need to do is add a repeater to show all the cases related to the project__c

```
<apex:repeat value="{!p.Cases__r}" var="case">
        <a href="/{!case.id}" id="{!case.Id}"  
        onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!case.Id}', '/{!case.id}/m?retURL=%2F{!case.id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">{!case.Open_Cases_TEXT__c} </a>
        </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: happy i could help :)